# C++ Mi arreglo no guarda el valor que le doy

Tags: c++

A la hora de llamar el metodo se detiene justo abajo del for, no hace esa linea y no sucede nada, no me tira ningun error tampoco, ni la menor idea de por qué el int *arreglo no guarda el valor...

```
int* ListaCuevasAdy::obtAdyacencias(){
    int * arreglo;
    if(cantidadAdy == 0){
        return nullptr;
    }
    else{
        shared_ptr<NodoListaCuevasAdy> ultimo = inicio; 
        for(int c = 1; c<=cantidadAdy;c++){
            arreglo[c] = ultimo->idCueva;
            ultimo = ultimo->sgtCueva;
        }     
    }
    return arreglo; 
}
```

Comment: Y `arrelgo` a donde crees que apunta? Si solo declaras `int * arreglo;`, declaraste un puntero que apunta a una direccion que no conoces. Probablemente cuando trates de escribir a esa direccion desconocida (`arreglo[c] = ultimo->idCueva`), el sistema operativo detenga tu programa. Para lo que quieres hacer, seria bueno que usaras `std::vector`. Y ya veo que estas usando `shared_ptr`, porque no usar un `unique_ptr<T[]>`?

Comment: o tambien podrias simplemente instanciarlo con un tamaño (int * arreglo = new[cantidadAdy+1];)